# How would I bold items within a Listbox?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, _
 ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) _
 Handles ListBox1.DrawItem

    ' Draw the background of the ListBox control for each item.
    e.DrawBackground()

    ' Define the default color of the brush as black. 
    Dim myFontStyle As FontStyle = FontStyle.Bold
    ' Determine the color of the brush to draw each item based on    
    ' the index of the item to draw. 
    Select Case e.Index
        Case 0
            'Set Font to Bold
        Case 1
            'Set Font to Normal

    End Select

    ' Draw the current item text based on the current  
    ' Font and the custom brush settings.
    e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.Items(e.Index).ToString(), _
    e.Font, e.Brush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault)
End Sub
```

I'm trying to make it so that I can bold certain items within the ListBox, however I'm running into a lot of trouble. I referred to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) however this changes the list items to differing colours, trying to adapt the code has yielded me no success. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try creating a font variable:

```
Dim useFont as Font = e.Font
Select Case e.Index
    Case 0
        'Set Font to Bold
      useFont = New Font(e.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
End Select

' Draw the current item text based on the current  
' Font and the custom brush settings.
e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.Items(e.Index).ToString(), _
useFont, e.Brush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault)
```